# UIKeyCommands of custom UITableView not recognized

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uiresponder, uikeycommand

I have a `UITableView` subclass that has the `keyCommands` property implemented, where there are several `UIKeyCommands` provided. This `UITableView` is a subview of the main view in the View Controller.

When I run the app and hold Command to preview the available keyboard shortcuts, those key commands do not show up.

I have tested this custom `UITableView` subclass in another project, and in a separate place in this project. In both cases, the table view belongs to a `UITableViewController` subclass instead of a plain `UIViewController` subclass, which I am using in this situation.

I tried to call `becomeFirstResponder` on the table view, but that did not make any difference.

Why are the table view's key commands not being recognized, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (I may be mistaken, but this is how it appears), the table view in UITableViewControllers has `canBecomeFirstResponder` return `true`, while the default value for UITableView is `false`.

To fix this, just add this method to the subclass:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```